# Passing UTM parameters using Google Tag Manager on iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to pass the UTM campaign parameter (which i have locally in the app from a different source) to Google Tag Manager along with the transaction event to be able to associate transactions to campaigns. I use the data layer to send the data: `[self.tagManager.dataLayer push:combinedParameters]` the event is set to transaction in the `combinedParameters`.

The transaction data is being tracked correctly but there is no associated campaign data like `utm_source`, `utm_medium` etc. visible in the Analytics website. I am passing all of them in `combinedParameters`. I also tried sending it through `[self.tagManager.dataLayer pushValue:val forKey:key];` using `utm_source` etc as keys and also using `kGAICampaignContent`.

None of which actually worked. There is no documentation (atleast i could find) which helps in understanding how to pass UTM data through GTM. The only available one is the [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder) one which does not work in this case.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to wrap your head around if you just consider the SDK to be a hit builder for Measurement Protocol.

In GTM, you can add [MP fields](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en) to a tag using the settings found under **More Settings** > **Fields to set**. To set the three required campaign parameters (source, medium, name), you would add the following fields:

Field name: &cm
Value: some-campaign-medium

Field name: &cs
Value: some-campaign-source

Field name: &cn
Value: some-campaign-name

To set the dynamic values for "some-campaign-*", you can use Data Layer Variables to pull the parsed URL parameter values into GTM's data model.

So, to parse a URL that's coming in, you could leverage the `dataLayer` as well as the `GAIDictionaryBuilder` interface of the GA SDK.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];

  GAIDictionaryBuilder *hitParams = [[GAIDictionaryBuilder alloc] init];
  [hitParams setCampaignParametersFromUrl:urlString];

  TAGDataLayer *dataLayer = [TAGManager instance].dataLayer;

  if([hitParams get:kGAICampaignSource] && [hitParams get:kGAICampaignMedium] && [hitParams get:kGAICampaignName]) {
    [dataLayer push:@{
      @"event": @"screenView", 
      @"screenName": @"Home Screen", 
      @"customCampaignSource": [hitParams get:kGAICampaignSource], 
      @"customCampaignMedium": [hitParams get:kGAICampaignMedium], 
      @"customCampaignName": [hitParams get:kGAICampaignName]
    }];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

After that, you'd create three Data Layer Variables, one for `customCampaignSource`, one for `customCampaignName`, and one for `customCampaignMedium`. Add those to the &cs, &cn, and &cm fields, respectively, and your Tags should collect dynamic campaign data.